# Why does setting the property in the constructor of a struct not work?

Tags: c#, properties, struct

I have following code which is not allowed (error below), why?

```
    struct A
    {
        private int b;

        public A(int x)
        {
            B = x;
        }
        public int B
        {
            get { return b; }
            set { b=value; }
        }

    }
```

I receive the following error:

> The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned
>   to     Field 'Test.x' must be fully assigned before control is returned
>   to the caller

Comment: check my answer you will get idea about it clearly

Answer (score 6):

A struct's variables all have to be definitely assigned before you can use any methods or properties. There are two possible fixes here:

1) You can explicitly call the parameterless constructor:

```
public A(int x) : this()
{
    B = x;
}
```

2) You can use the field instead of the property:

```
public A(int x)
{
    b = x;
}
```

Of course the second option only works in your current form - you *have* to use the first option if you want to change your struct to use an automatic property.

However, importantly, you now have a mutable struct. This is almost always a **very bad idea**. I would *strongly* urge you to use something like this instead:

```
struct A
{
    private readonly int b;

    public A(int x)
    {
        b = x;
    }

    public int B { get { return b; } }
}
```

EDIT: More details of why the original code doesn't work...

From section 11.3.8 of the C# spec:

> If the struct instance constructor doesn't specify a constructor initializer, the `this` variable corresponds to an `out` parameter of the struct type

Now initially that won't be definitely assigned, which means you can't execute *any* member function (including property setters) until all the firsts of the struct being constructed have been definitely assigned. The compiler doesn't *know* or try to take account of the fact that the property setter doesn't try to read from another field. It's all in aid of avoiding reading from fields which haven't been definitely assigned.

Comment: Well I do not understand. What is the difference between setting to property which does the same (b=value) and doing it manually? Still I cannot see why B=x does not work. BTW struct variables are fields or I should call them variables?

Comment: @Cocodrilo - because you can't do *anything* with a struct until it is fully initialised, which can be by calling the default (and, as it happens, fake) constructor, or can be by assigning all the fields explicitly. You can't access a property (which is a method) until that is done. "1" above shows the first option (constructor), "2" above shows the "assign all the fields" option.

Comment: @Cocodrilo and just to second Jon's point; mutable structs are very very bad mojo.

Comment: @Cocodrilo: See my edit - it's really useful to read the C# spec for this, to be honest.

Comment: Well I am now lost. What is bad on mutable struct? I thought I could work with it just like with class (except for being a value type)

Comment: @Cocodrilo: Just one example: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2008/05/14/mutating-readonly-structs.aspx See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil and various other questions, blog posts etc.

Comment: @Cocodrilo, just because **you** know that the setter just sets the field, don't assume that the compiler knows too. As far as it's concerned B=x calls a method (like *set_B(x)*) and that method could do anything at all, including accessing other fields, that might have not been initialized.

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor to:

```
public A(int x) :
    this()
{
    B = x;
}
```

As to "why", refer to [11.3.8 Constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664479%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) and [5.3 Definite assignment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691172%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: @Gunner : This code will remove this error If not you will have an error as The 'this' object cannot be used before all of its fields are assigned